# Why is free memory not used as disk cache?

Tags: linux-kernel, zfs, cache

My file server says:

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8023836     5250252     2534480         668      239104     2515488
Swap:      18942984      175616    18767368
```

There is a lot of disk reads going on (terabytes of data), so I am puzzled why it reserves 2.5 GB as free and only 0.24 GB as disk cache. Why not use the 2.5 GB for read cache?

Can I change that, so that more of the 2.5 GB will be used for disk cache?

```
$ uname -a
Linux hpdisk 5.4.0-51-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 14:28:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub in progress since Sun Nov  8 00:24:02 2020
        4.77T scanned at 6.44M/s, 4.74T issued at 6.39M/s, 13.7T total
        0B repaired, 34.50% done, no estimated completion time
config:

        NAME                                                                                                           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool                                                                                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                                                                                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
            dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-b5e46de8249645e882a3985615ac4e7d-crypto-ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_1EG575KZ              ONLINE       0     0     0
            dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-a095d853c023483994c1f9e34c4d28ab-crypto-ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_1EHU5BJZ              ONLINE       0     0     0
            dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-3548b790c63746718b03cdbfbcefc80c-crypto-ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_2SGGB3JW              ONLINE       0     0     0
            dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-bab3c8fe77e84d2abc8cd2b06c4f8957-crypto-ata-WDC_WD80EMAZ-00WJTA0_2YJ5N8WD              ONLINE       0     0     0
            dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-99a487a3939c45ceb4cac9cf4bf4fd69-crypto-ata-WDC_WD80EZAZ-11TDBA0_2SG9J57J              ONLINE       0     0     0
        logs
          mirror-1                                                                                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
            dm-uuid-part1-CRYPT-LUKS2-c0601a7ef87743888ea6de49046925dc-crypto-scsi-SATA_Crucial_CT525MX3_1711164B7A3E  ONLINE       0     0     0
            dm-uuid-part1-CRYPT-LUKS2-ba2220b00f8c4702a3ad2d83144f9cef-crypto-scsi-SATA_Crucial_CT525MX3_173818CFFE43  ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          dm-uuid-part2-CRYPT-LUKS2-ba2220b00f8c4702a3ad2d83144f9cef-crypto-scsi-SATA_Crucial_CT525MX3_173818CFFE43    ONLINE       0     0     0
          dm-uuid-part2-CRYPT-LUKS2-c0601a7ef87743888ea6de49046925dc-crypto-scsi-SATA_Crucial_CT525MX3_1711164B7A3E    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pool is running a scrub. After stopping the scrub cache was used as normal (0.24 GB free, the rest used as cache).

```
$ sudo zpool scrub -s rpool
[...wait...]
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8023836     4043000      241208         680     3739628     3714144
Swap:      18942984      175360    18767624
```

I have no idea why scrub should cause this behaviour, and right now I need the I/O, so the scrub will have to wait.